# Mounted() não executado

Tags: vue.js

Estou trabalhando com Vue , e estou fazendo uma view onde ficarão os cupons de descontos. Criei um component.vue para os cupons.

Na view onde os cupons serão exibidos eu bati na API para pegar os dados.

```
<template>
    <div id="couponAndPartnership">
        <div class="content central">
            <div id="results"
                v-if="coupons && coupons.length > 0">
                <Coupon
                        v-for="coupon of coupons"
                        :key="coupon._id"
                >
                </Coupon>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Coupon from "@/components/Coupon.vue";
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                coupons: []
            };
        },
        components:{
            Coupon
        },
        methods:{
            mounted(){
                console.log("passou no mounted");
                this.axios
                    .get("https:URL/coupons")
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            this.coupons = response.data;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.loading = false;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo exibir nada na tela. e o erro que vem é 304.E aparentemente ele não está nem entrando no mounted() porque não imprime nada no console do navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu caro, tire o `mounted` não é um método do Vue e sim uma etapa do ciclo de vida da instância. Ou seja, mova o `mounted()` de `methods` para a raiz da `classe` e tente novamente. Assim:

`

```
export default {
        data(){
            return{
                coupons: []
            };
        },
        components:{
            Coupon
        },
        mounted(){
            console.log("passou no mounted");
            this.axios
                .get("https:URL/coupons")
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.coupons = response.data;
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
            }
        methods:{
        },
    }
`
```

Comment: Funcionou.  Esse era o único problema

Comment: Ótimo, que bom que funcionou